# Declarative service requirements in MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Is there a declarative way to specify references to other components in MEF?
Sorry  I'm new to .NET, and found [this msdn MEF tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which only declares references in the code.

What I am asking is whether you can specify this part:

```
[Import(typeof(ICalculator))]
public ICalculator calculator;
```

as something like this in some sort of properties file:

```
Requires-Component: ICalculator
```

As some of you can probably tell, I am trying to mimic the way OSGi works (Java land), especially Declarative Services part of it.

Comment: The attribute IS a form of declaration

Comment: Ok, how about `catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly))`?

Comment: If you want to collect all MEF dependencies you can use reflection just as MEF does to collect them and produce a "properties file" which would be like a report of dependencies. Not sure what you are asking about though.

Answer (score 2):

MEF is based on the concept of a *catalogs* that contain *composable parts* that import and export other *composable parts* identified by *contract names*. This is very abstract, but in most cases the parts in MEF are types that via imports depend on other types (e.g. to create an object graph the root object depends other objects further down the graph). The contract names are the names of the types.

However, you can build on top of the MEF framework and create your own parts with dependencies. Then you will no longer use `AssemblyCatalog` (which works on types annotated with attributes) but instead you will have to implement your own `ServiceCatalog` that you can build from say "properties files". You will also have to implement your own parts by deriving from the abstract `ComposablePartDefinition` class and the abstract `ComposablePart` class. MEF would then be able to create parts and connect them according to the imports and exports you have defined using your own contract names.

Comment: I see, so these catalogs basically manage "static" dependencies? Can I "hide" certain classes or interfaces in components with this approach?

Comment: In MEF you don't hide stuff. You declare what you need (imports) and what you provide (exports). The rest (that you don't declare) is "hidden".

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I meant by hiding! :-) So can I specify these imports and exports declaratively? Sorry if I misunderstood your answer, but I am still not clear on that...

Comment: Perhaps just to explain the reasoning behind the "want" of doing these things declaratively: I want my code to remain framework-independent, neutral, and have no traces of MEF or anything else. Thanks!

Comment: MEF is based on a very abstract layer of _composable parts_, _imports_ and _exports_, and then a very concrete layer that applies the abstract principles to composing .NET object graphs from types described by attributes. If I understand your question correctly you only want to use the abstract parts of MEF because you want to model service dependencies. To do this you will have to implement all your own stuff on top of the abstract MEF base layer. And you will not be able to find much help doing this because 99% of MEF code samples on the net is about composing types.

Comment: Not sure what you want to compose, but if you want to compose types but want to avoid the attributes have a look at `TypeCatalog`. You can easily design an XML file format and instantiate your own `TypeCatalog` from that. That would be very "java-like" I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I always ask bad questions... man, why is it so hard to ask a question?  I'll try to come up with a better wording and post it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll take a look at that! But please note, that this has nothing to do with being java-like, and everything to do with have clean code, that can be understood by a person who doesn't know anything about MEF.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this clarification in a comment:

> *I want my code to remain framework-independent, neutral, and have no traces of MEF or anything else.*

When you look at other dependency injection frameworks, you'll see that there are three common strategies for configuring components:

1. configuration files
2. configuration in code (separate from the component code)
3. attributes on the component types

From your comment, it looks like you want to avoid the third approach, since it "pollutes" the component code with a dependency on the dependency injection framework. I don't disagree.

Currently 3. is the only approach supported in MEF out of the box. (You *can* implement your own `ExportProvider` or `ComposablePartCatalog` to do 1. or 2., but that's a rather advanced use case).

In the next .NET 4.5 release (currently in beta) MEF will support option 2 out of the box. It's called the [MEF convention model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2011/03/08/mef-s-convention-model.aspx).

Alternatively, you could just use [another dependency injection container](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).
At least [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/externalconfig.html), [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html) and [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConfiguringStructureMap.htm) have support for external configuration files.

However, I would recommend option 2. configuration in code because it is easier to maintain than an external configuration file, while still keeping the configuration separate from the component code. Take a look at some of the other containers like [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) or [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).